# Pimera vez ejecutando un programa de ejemplo

Tags: java-8

Buenas tardes

Soy nuevo en java estoy tratando de ejecutar mi primer programa en java 
al compilar este ejemplo me sale una ventana con dos opciones le he dado a ambas y en las dos me arroja un error, anexo imagenes para mayor explicacion.
Podrian ayudarme con este caso, por favor

[image: seleccionando java aplication]

[image: error al trata de compilar]

Comment: Hola @jcamperos. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta, agregando el código y el tecto del error? Las imágenes pueden ser usadas para aportar más detalles, pero no para tu código. Pensemos en personas con dispositivos con pantallas chicas o con problemas de vista, o si alguien quisiera copiar tu código y probarlo.

Answer (score 1):

El modificador de acceso debe ser `public` no `Public`, te sugiero revises la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html